# useState on startDate not updating the date when I use setStartDate

Tags: reactjs, use-state, tsx

here is my codes

```
import format from "date-fns/format";
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

const startTime = setHours(setMinutes(date, 0), hour);
console.log(startTime); // showing correct date and time as I set

setStartDate(startTime);
console.log(startDate); // this is showing current date and time
```

But when I do

```
console.log(startDate);
```

I get current date and time. However if I do

```
console.log(startTime);
```

It shows the correct date and time as I want it.

Can you please help. I am using tsx format of React. Developer is not available for another few hours and I have to deliver this quickly to my client.

Comment: Is `setHours` a dispatch function? If not, what it it? Dispatch functions don't return anything

Comment: @CertainPerformance same question for `setMinutes`, too

Comment: I am using date-fns like this
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` is an asynchronous function. By the time you are trying to read the state, it's in execution and its value is yet to be updated. Consider the following example:

```js
//Defining the state
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());


const startTime = setHours(setMinutes(date, 0), hour); //Calculating new state
console.log(startTime); // Works fine due to synchronouse behaviour

setStartDate(startTime);  //Async, will wait if any other state updates are in pipeline. If not, it'll try to update asynchronously
console.log(startDate); // By the time you reach here it's still updating and pointing to the old value.
```

If you want to read the new value, you may consider using `useEffect(fn,[])`. In your case, you can read a new state as follows:

```js
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(startDate); // Fires whenever startDate changes
  },[startDate])
```

You can visit [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-meadow-jjil3?file=/src/App.js) here for a working demo. Also, you can read more about `useEffect` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect)[Detailed]

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are a life save :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing error on these last two lines

```
setStartDate(startTime);
console.log(startDate);
```

If you set startDate to startTime it will definately show you the current date and time.Hopefully it works